# Fix ADB "Performing Streamed Install" Taking Long Time

Tags: adb

I'm testing my app on my real device. Just a day ago `adb install .apk` works perfect.
But now it takes a lot of time just about 5-10 minutes for installing 7 MB of apk.

Note: I'm not using wired connection, I'm using `adb tcpip 5555` to serve without wire. As it works grate when connect with cable.

I have done every thing which i know: Restarting Device, Revoking Certificates, turning on-off USB debugging and reconnecting over network.

If i am doning anything wrong please guide me.

Comment: You can try to use `adb push` for uploading the file and them `adb shell pm install <pkfile>` on device. This way you can learn if uploading (-> Wifi) or installing is the problem.

Comment: hey! thanks for your help but i cannot run build from android studio as it only run `adb install .apk`

Comment: If you are in Android Studio then just generate the APK and install it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I JUST GOT MY ANSWER!!

I was connecting my phone with internal ip (`92.168.*`), i don't why but this was issue and when i connect my phone over public (`25.43.*`) it just work!! :D

Comment: Thanks for contributing your solution, Adarsh – that's the spirit! <3 Could you please clarify what you mean by "internal" and "public"? Of course you can "sanitize" any IP addresses used (e.g. `127.0.0.1` doesn't need that, but e.g. `192.168.*` would make clear it's a "private network" all your home devices are connected to, or `123.123.*.*` could stand for any IP accessible from the "outer world". I'm especially wondering if you really needed the latter.

Comment: I have edited my answer but now there is speed issue, can i get any help?

Comment: Thanks for th dit! You meant `192.168.*`  for the internal one  guess? The leading `1` somehow got lost. Still strange that you have to use the public address. As for the speed issue: Maybe asking a separate question (linking to this one here for context)?